# Tableau dashboard refresh using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tableau-api

Is there a way to refresh Tableau dashboards using Python? I need to refresh Tableau dashboards after my data is loaded into DB.

Comment: Do you mean to refresh extracts or truly just 'hit the refresh button' on a live dashboard?

Comment: I wana "Hit the refresh button" basically

Comment: Is this for something like a dashboard being displayed on a big-screen? or for users who might hit the dashboard in the near future who want a cached view?

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken. We need to refresh the reports when new data is loaded into the database. We load data into DB with Python and we wanted to refresh Tableau reports asap we load new data into Database.

Comment: Refresh is kind of a tricky term, though. What is the use case? Lets say a new batch of data is entered via Python to the DB - do you want to refresh the __Extract__ on Tableau Server? Or do you want some view that is already being displayed to refresh? Or do you just want your users to not hit old data when they click on that dashboard in the future - So they dont have to click refresh themselves?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I wanted to refresh the Extract on Tableau Server when a new batch of data is entered via Python to the DB and not only Python do we have this feasibility to be implemented using any language or process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tableau [REST API](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref.htm#run_extract_refresh_task) will allow you to refresh your extracts via Python.

Here is an [example](https://community.tableau.com/thread/287767) of a script which should get you started:

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC

tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth(user, password)
server = TSC.Server('Address')
server.version = '2.3'
resource_id= 6109
with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
print('connection made')
print(server.version)
#resource = server.workbooks.get_by_id(resource_id)
server.workbooks.refresh(workbook_id='6109')

server.auth.sign_out()
print('connection closed')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel. Will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code if you want to find workbook with name and refresh it.
**note : your data should be extracted not live, otherwise this will throw an exception.**

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC

address = 'https://your_site_address.com'
token = "generate_token_from_tableau"
tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth("token_name", token)
 
server = TSC.Server(address)
#Try adding this row to use the correct api version
server.use_server_version()

#if SSL verify true
server.add_http_options({'verify': True, 'cert': 'your_cert.crt'})
#if SSL verify not required
server.add_http_options({'verify': False})
server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth)
# print(server.workbooks.all())
req_option = TSC.RequestOptions()
req_option.filter.add(TSC.Filter(TSC.RequestOptions.Field.Name, TSC.RequestOptions.Operator.Equals, 'work_book_name'))
r = server.workbooks.get(req_option)
print(type(r[0][0]), r)
server.workbooks.refresh(r[0][0])
```