# Data Refresh on Tableau Server

Tags: csv, tableau-api

I have created a Tableau dashboard with a live connection to a csv file which gets updated time and again. My workbook in Tableau desktop is getting updated with the latest data but my dashboard on Tableau server does not update no matter what. Am I missing something here? would appreciate your help here

Answer (score 0):

The tableau dashboard on tableau server will not get updated as the csv file is local to your system.
I would recommend a database if data is very dynamically changing. In case if you have no option other than csv then one thing that you can do is:

1. Update the tableau dashboard on your local system by refreshing it
2. Publish this workbook to the tableau server in the same path of the previous dashboard, you will be asked if you want to replace the older one
3. Click yes and you're done.

This is one solution that I could think off.

If the data is not huge <5000000 cells then you can use google sheets which is free and can provide live connection to your tableau server dashboard.

Hope this helps.!

Comment: @anki you can also use the REST API of Tableau with Abhishek's solution to automate it. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55654289/tableau-dashboard-refresh-using-python

Comment: thanks @Abhishek and Monika for your comments. Just another question, do you think it would work if I use "Extract" instead of live connection and make that refresh?

Comment: Google sheets live connection or extract should do for you!

Comment: @AbhishekBoorugu due to some business restrictions, I cannot use Google sheets. The CSV file on the remote machine is my only data source. So I should try out extract to see how it functions. Thanks for your inputs on this